# How to stop Jsplumb creating a new connection while editing the nodes?

Tags: jquery, jsplumb, detach

I'm using JSPlumb, having the issue with my connected nodes. while editing the nodes, it does not remove the previous connection and creating a new connection on the existing node.

This is the method that i'm using:

```
jsPlumb.select({source:node1, target:node2}).detach();
```

This is my JSFiddle link: **https://jsfiddle.net/g2acL6jv/**

Comment: If problem is with edit...please scale down demo to only represent that problem. We shouldn't have to fill out multiple rows of form and figure out how your UI works to see the problem.

Comment: i agree but when add some row there is no issue after edit any link, it not detach  and it edit with connect new line but not detach previous line, please check.

Comment: check what? You haven't provided any steps for us to follow to reproduce your issue. I see that demo and I have no idea what to enter and have to create several rows of it and just say to myself .... "no point doing this". If you want help then create [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with guidance on what steps need to be followed.